# make slick slider only show 3 item

Tags: jquery, html, slick.js

hello i use slick slider and want to show only 3 image

but it left half image in both side

```
<div class="review-company">
    div><img src="http://placehold.it/350x350"></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/350x350"></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/350x350"></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/350x350"></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/350x350"></div>
    </div><!-- Review-company -->

 $('.review-company').slick({
      centerMode: true,
      centerPadding: '60px',
      slidesToShow: 3,
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 768,
          settings: {
            arrows: false,
            centerMode: true,
            centerPadding: '40px',
            slidesToShow: 3
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 480,
          settings: {
            arrows: false,
            centerMode: true,
            centerPadding: '40px',
            slidesToShow: 1
          }
        }
      ]
    });
```

how to make it only show 3 image with empty space in left and right?

Comment: Using `centerMode` will do that. Do you have to use `centerMode`?

Comment: ya i already use that sir

Comment: I'm asking if you need to use `centerMode`. If you set it to `false` you won't see the partial slides.

Comment: fixed with you. thx sirr ah i cant give i thuumbs up

Answer (score 2):

just make centerMode false

got it from @Yass